# Прервать foreach, добавить строку и продолжить цикл

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Столкнулся с интересной задачей. При парсинге пагинации с другого сайта, парсятся только ссылки, из-за чего в пагинации пропадает страница, на которой находишься, так как это не ссылка, а блочный элемент.
Нагуглил, что foreach можно прервать и продолжить, но какое задать условие для его продолжения, я не понял. Может есть другие способы?

Вот код:

```
foreach ($html->find('.paginator a') as $pagination) {
    echo '<a href="/'.$pagination->plaintext.'">'.$pagination->plaintext.'</a>';

    if ($pagination->plaintext == '') {
        break;
        echo '<span class="pagination-current">'.$_GET['page'].'</span>';
    }
}
```

Да и то, что я понаписал - не работает. Первая часть пагинации не отображается.

Comment: Подскажите, зачем вам цикл то прерывать? Как четко звучит задача?

Comment: @KirillBabinec что бы вставить блок <span class="current">$_GET['page']</span>

Comment: @KirillBabinec мне нужно в цикле вставить страницу, на которой я сейчас нахожусь. В цикле ее нет, так как она не парсится, и просто пропускается. То есть пагинация получается такая: 1 2 4 5. А нужно 1 2 **3** 4 5

Comment: Вы бы привели код который парсите, с классами и блоками. Может вам достаточно расширить ваш цикл, добавив, чтобы он находил и блочный элемент, а внутри цикла уже проверяйте ссылка это ли текущая страница: `$html->find('.paginator a, .pagination-current')` - так в цикл будут включеные все классы `.paginator a` и `.pagination-current`

Comment: @Tunker удивительно, первый раз вижу, что можно перечислять классы для поиска. И это сработало, дальше уже условием выставил то, что надо. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам достаточно расширить ваш цикл, добавив, чтобы он находил и блочный элемент, а внутри цикла уже проверяйте ссылка это ли текущая страница: `$html->find('.paginator a, .pagination-current')` - так в цикл будут включены все классы `.paginator a` и `.pagination-current`